# Get today's featured article with Wikipedia API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm eventually trying to get the intro section of the article, but first I just need to figure out how to get the article itself. Looking into the API I've gotten this link:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&action=featuredfeed&feed=featured&rvparse=1

which takes me to a feed of the featured articles but 1) the links on that page don't work and 2) hasn't there got to be an easier way to get specifically today's featured article?

Comment: Please search the internet on how to process/read from a feed. StackOverflow is geared towards helping fix troublesome code, not provide it. Try [Google's Feed API to start](https://developers.google.com/feed/).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty cool scraped feed site for Wikipedia's Featured Article of the Day:

http://jeays.net/wikipedia/featured.xml

I'm not familiar with their API at all, but this feed could be a good source to get your project going fast while you figure out how to scrape the feed yourself. (Depending on the purpose of your app, relying on this feed may not be the best idea in case it goes belly-up.)

Now you'd just need to parse the XML :)

Comment: This feed hasn't updated since around the time this answer was posted